# Django Beginner Forms, not able to make two forms work on one template page

Tags: python, django, forms, templates

I would like to have more than one form on a page. So far I have a simple form that a user enters numbers and gets a number returned. When I trying to add another form (which will be Post2 in my models) on the same page I cant. I end up getting the same form twice.

All help appreciated.

Made an edit adding in an attempt to get second form working
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from django.contrib import admin
from amat.views import AmatView

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', AmatView.as_view(), name='home'),

    ]
```

oddsmat.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="form1"/>
</form>

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="form2"/>
</form>


... 


{{ round1 }}
{{ round2 }}
{{ round3 }}
{{ betround1 }}
{{ betround2 }}
{{ betround3 }}

<br>
its the same as {{ thesameas }}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from amat.forms import AmatForm

# Create your views here.


class AmatView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'oddsmat.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = AmatForm()

        args = {
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = AmatForm(request.POST)
        if  form.is_valid():

            round1 = form.cleaned_data['round1']
            round2 = form.cleaned_data['round2']            
            round3 = form.cleaned_data['round3']            
            form = AmatForm()
            betround1 = ((round2+1)*(round3+1))/((round1)*(round2+2)+(round2)*(round3+2)+(round3)*(round1+2)+3)
            betround2 = ((round1+1)*(round3+1))/((round1)*(round2+2)+(round2)*(round3+2)+(round3)*(round1+2)+3)
            betround3 = ((round2+1)*(round1+1))/((round1)*(round2+2)+(round2)*(round3+2)+(round3)*(round1+2)+3)
            thesameas = round1*betround1-betround2-betround3

            args = {
                "form": form,
                "round1":round1,
                "round2":round2,
                "round3":round3,
                "betround1":betround1,
                "betround2":betround2,
                "betround3":betround3,
                "thesameas":thesameas,
            }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

class AmatView2(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'oddsmat.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = AmatForm2()

        args = {
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = AmatForm2(request.POST)
        if  form.is_valid():

            round10 = form.cleaned_data['round10']
            round11= form.cleaned_data['round11']            

            form = AmatForm2()



            args = {
                "form": form,
                "round10":round10,
                "round11":round11,

            }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):

    round1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5)
    round2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5)
    round3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Post2(models.Model):
    round10 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5)
    round11 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from amat.models import Post, 

 class AmatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Post
         fields = ('round1', 'round2', 'round3')

class AmatForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post2
        fields = ('round10', 'round11')
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Where are you using two forms?

Comment: You have 2 models, but only one model form. You need a ModelForm for every Model here (the inner Meta class says it all: **model = Post**)

Comment: You don't pass second form to your template, you should create it with constructor and then pass, not seperate fields, and you create only a Post form, while you should create a Post2 form, as well.

Comment: @Fazil Zaid I'm not able to make two forms work on one. I not getting errors I simple dont know where to even begin( ive been at it for hours)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want a page for example  where a user can find the volume of a cube by entering the length width and height. Or on the same page using another form find the volume of a sphere by entering only radius

Comment: @dentemm I tried that but I wasn't able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate views, and they only return a specific form. In your template you repeat the code, therefore you get it twice. A return supports any number of forms. In your view you could do like:

```
form1 = AmatForm()
form2 = AmatForm2()

args = {
'form2' = form1
'form2' = form2
}
return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

In your template you can then use:

```
{{ form1.as_p }}
{{ form2.as_p }}
```

I suggest to either make the form fields optional, and then check if any data was entered, otherwise you run into trouble with empty form fields.

Comment: Thank you @Claude this helped me get the answer.